# Детектирование статической функции

Tags: c++, static, this

Есть такой макрос

```cpp
#define TEST printf("%p", this)
```

Когда его вызываешь из обычного метода - проблем нет

```cpp
void CMyClass::Test() {
  TEST;
}
```

Но когда его вызываешь из статического метода

```cpp
static void CMyClass::TestStatic() {
  TEST;
}
```

получаешь ошибку о том, что идентификатор `this` не определен. Что логично.

Вопрос: а нельзя ли как-то определить, что мы находимся внутри статической функции и в соответствии с этим принимать решение об использовании кода? Т.е. как-то так

```cpp
#define TEST \
  #if declared(this) \
    printf("%p", this) \
  #else \
    printf("%p", nullptr) \
  #endif
```

или так

```cpp
#define TEST \
  if constexp (is_declared(this) \
    printf("%p", this); \
  else \
    printf("%p", nullptr)
```

Макрос используется для логирования вызовов

Comment: Поскольку макросы раскрываются до трансляции кода, то думаю, это сделать нельзя.

Comment: @avp `if constexpr` вычисляется уже на этапе компиляции и позволяет выбрасывать куски кода. Т.е. `if constexpr(std::is_static_method(...))` могло бы решить проблему

Comment: Да, "динамическая" (на уровне использования констант времени компиляции (вроде sizeof)) проверка спасет ситуацию. Но это уже к Страуструпу (и др. создателям языка)

Comment: Тогда вам нужно передавать этот метод в макрос. В заданном вопросе такая возможность отсутствует :)

Comment: @Harry макрос вызывается из этого метода. Т.е. нужно определить находимся ли мы в статическом контексте. Или узнать определен ли идентифиатор `this`

Comment: `#define TEST( T ) printf("%p", (void*)T)` => `TEST(this)` || `TEST(0)`

Comment: @AlexGlebe И это короче, чем использовать `std::is_static_method(...)` и передавать в макрос имя метода :)

Comment: @AlexGlebe Тогда уж проще сделать два макроса - один для статических, а другой - для не статических.

Comment: @user7860670 вот сейчас два макроса и используются

Answer (score 6, accepted):

При желании можно изловчиться определять, находится ли блок кода внутри статической или нестатической функции, например вот так:

```
#include <source_location>
#include <iostream>
#include <string_view>

#define CHECK_STATIC                                          \
    if constexpr                                              \
    (                                                         \
        ::std::string_view::npos != ::std::string_view        \
        {                                                     \
            ::std::source_location::current().function_name() \
        }.find("static ")                                     \
    )                                                         \
    {                                                         \
        ::std::cout << "in static" << ::std::endl;            \
    }                                                         \
    else                                                      \
    {                                                         \
        ::std::cout << "in non-static" << ::std::endl;        \
    }

struct Struct
{
    void NonStatic(void)
    {
        CHECK_STATIC;
    }
    static void Static(void)
    {
        CHECK_STATIC;
    }
};
 
int main(int, char const* const[])
{
    Struct s{};
    s.NonStatic();
    s.Static();
    return 0;
}
```

> --std=c++20 -Wall -Wextra -Wconversion -Wpedantic

> in non-static
> in static

[online compiler](https://godbolt.org/#z:OYLghAFBqd5QCxAYwPYBMCmBRdBLAF1QCcAaPECAM1QDsCBlZAQwBtMQBGAFlJvoCqAZ0wAFAB4gA5AAYppAFZdSrZrVDIApACYAQjt2kR7ZATx1KmWugDCqVgFcAtrRABmAKykr6ADJ5aTAA5ZwAjTGIQAA5SAAdUIUJzWjtHF3cveMSzOn9AkKdwyJjjTFNkhgJmYgJU51dPI0wTHNpK6oI84LCI6KMqmrr0xqEBzoDuwt6ogEojVAdiZA4pHTcA5EcsAGpNNxshBaXMAH1WVBZWvexNGQBBNY2tzF3981HiTGYna9uH7XWtE2Dh2ewOBGIAWAJwAbnhMAB3X73P5rLBUCbbGwACWwNgA0icGAAVO7EgCSNm21JptLp9IZjPpmg8Nj%2BtLwVG2aFoo0w4lixCZwpFotpLLZ91pEDFsrlcol7IZIBAo3QKo%2BUNh8IRKtoWW2YDAewAItsNQR1aqIVq4YjGYqpQzNAB2XTyj2e6mOu6ii1Ww6LZZnC7MVoq5CLT70CAzAB0VAcQNaJ1o30wsd2rKVzJdJoTAXQEB02lGYbwyF22m0My9np9tNrdebCuzTu9bpbXdFDeV1qtaAcBFebP2Ve0AW2ZbMWmrI7B5v7Kp8rD27pFvY7Zu7O%2Bdbd9NOaIl3J6zkoPHfXp5Pm7p/ojC2HYIXJcntDoAFppxWS/Ox/eQBXNcHX3cU81Re4PgcUxtkqYhoIIVE3RzbYYVQPB0G2II6HaGcIDQjCZhQ119HbOkcTxQkSTJSk12I8CyO/SsCMw3CK3w9D0CIsiSJQ2kKIJIlSQpUdSIvXYGIecC3DE3Z7gCYcnGYAIIAU0huQQapuToUYACptN5RCPH0DwTW4qTZJpOCEKnXjpMs6khDjbC2iqPCiJklCnLY5BYzosjPgIRZaG2GR/Kkk0/ikOZWGkDx5FcWR5FQaQ2T0AwpyOZYqzcTh5AIaQ5BmOYAGsQA8GQVGkbgEsK5LpHkIQQEqgqkrmOBYCQfkyiHEhyEoapgCEUQ1GaBgEFQBFEry0g0CcWI8FUVoRsCVhxsmxK5Fm1B5sW3pgE4Q7tt29hiAAeSHdaprq7xxDKO5iCGhrbrKSp8ES%2BR%2BEYFh2C4XgvuEMRJCSxRlFUdQUAMAwVDwUImsgOZUFiVomqkD8v0tU1Z30PRtBkbYPwAdTYVgCcJ/kIWYMmeRhCJEjoMnYkwdA1BnRqso4Th%2Bnelaxom66pBmhFiGYWJpDymK4tqkGUqkcQogANg/BXuG2YBkErQ6404bZsDuyMiCFCBcEIEgcs4Ws0px3R8rq4rSAQL4sEiWNSDKiqqqkGrSCcLgZEqzb6qkRrmtIVqislqRtGlrbZdttq5lp4h6dcbggA%3D)

Однако использовать `this` все равно не выйдет, так как это ключевое слово не может появляться в статических функциях и подобная ситуация приведет к ошибке синтаксиса еще до того, как будет вычислено `if constexpr`. И вообще, макросы - зло. Делайте нормальные функции.

Comment: Как функция решит эту проблему? Я все равно должен буду написать две функции (пусть и перегруженные) и вызывать то одну, то вторую

Comment: Вопрос у вас поставлен как *"а нельзя ли как-то определить, что мы находимся внутри статической функции и в соответствии с этим принимать решение об использовании кода?"* - я написал пример, демонстрирующий, как это сделать. Ну а в конце поясняется почему с this это вам не поможет и все равно придется делать два варианта - см. https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=VyQOnn2K_zw